# Swift: TitleForHeaderInSection Issue with Executing

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I just can't seem to get it right, as far as calling naming my headers is concerned.

If you are wondering what my model is about - it's basically a dictionary containing beautiful places, written alphabetically.

May anyone help me out, because I can't really figure out what I am doing wrong?

```
import UIKit

class PlacesTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return model.places.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        switch section {
        case 0: return (model.places["A"]!.count)
        case 1: return (model.places["B"]!.count)
        case 2: return (model.places["C"]!.count)
        case 3: return (model.places["F"]!.count)
        case 4: return (model.places["G"]!.count)
        case 5: return (model.places["H"]!.count)
        case 6: return (model.places["M"]!.count)
        case 7: return (model.places["N"]!.count)
        case 8: return (model.places["P"]!.count)
        case 9: return (model.places["R"]!.count)
        case 10: return (model.places["S"]!.count)
        case 11: return (model.places["T"]!.count)
        case 12: return (model.places["V"]!.count)
        case 13: return (model.places["Y"]!.count)
        case 14 : return (model.places["Z"]!.count)
        default: return 1
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PlacesCell", for: indexPath)

        switch indexPath.section {
        case 0: cell.textLabel?.text = model.places["A"]?[indexPath.row]
        case 1: cell.textLabel?.text = model.places["B"]?[indexPath.row]
        case 2: cell.textLabel?.text = model.places["C"]?[indexPath.row]
        case 3: cell.textLabel?.text = model.places["F"]?[indexPath.row]
        case 4: cell.textLabel?.text = model.places["G"]?[indexPath.row]
        case 5: cell.textLabel?.text = model.places["H"]?[indexPath.row]
        case 6: cell.textLabel?.text = model.places["M"]?[indexPath.row]
        case 7: cell.textLabel?.text = model.places["N"]?[indexPath.row]
        case 8: cell.textLabel?.text = model.places["P"]?[indexPath.row]
        case 9: cell.textLabel?.text = model.places["R"]?[indexPath.row]
        case 10: cell.textLabel?.text = model.places["S"]?[indexPath.row]
        case 11: cell.textLabel?.text = model.places["T"]?[indexPath.row]
        case 12: cell.textLabel?.text = model.places["V"]?[indexPath.row]
        case 13: cell.textLabel?.text = model.places["Y"]?[indexPath.row]
        case 14: cell.textLabel?.text = model.places["Z"]?[indexPath.row]
        default: break
        }
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HeaderCell")
        switch section {
        case 0: cell?.textLabel?.text = "A"
        case 1: cell?.textLabel?.text = "B"
        case 2: cell?.textLabel?.text = "C"
        case 3: cell?.textLabel?.text = "F"
        case 4: cell?.textLabel?.text = "G"
        case 5: cell?.textLabel?.text = "H"
        case 6: cell?.textLabel?.text = "M"
        case 7: cell?.textLabel?.text = "N"
        case 9: cell?.textLabel?.text = "P"
        case 10: cell?.textLabel?.text = "R"
        case 11: cell?.textLabel?.text = "S"
        case 12: cell?.textLabel?.text = "T"
        case 13: cell?.textLabel?.text = "Y"
        case 14: cell?.textLabel?.text = "Z"
        default: break
        }

        return String(describing: cell)
    }
}
```

Comment: Contrary to what you might think, a UITableView header view is of type UITableViewHeaderFooterView and not UITableViewCell.  You should load it from a nib instead of using dequeReuseableCell.  Alternatively use UICollectionView which does have reusable header/footer views in the form of UICollectionReusableView.

Comment: @JoshHomann The OP isn't using `viewForHeader` or `viewForFooter`. The OP is using `titleForHeader...` so a simple string is all that is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're killing me smalls. ;)

```
import UIKit

class PlacesTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    let letters = ["A", "B", "C", "F", "G", "H", "M", "N", "P", "R", "S", "T", "V", "Y", "Z"]

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return model.places.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let letter = letters[section]
        return model.places[letter]?.count ?? 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PlacesCell", for: indexPath)
        let letter = letters[indexPath.section]
        cell.textLabel?.text = model.places[letter]?[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        let letter = letters[section]
        return letter
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Have a look at [UITableViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdelegate) for further info.

To edit the actual header view you'll want to use [viewForHeaderInSection](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614901-tableview) specifically.

Comment: Thank you very much! :) 

May you mind a follow-up question? How would I style the sections, then? Like changing the font size or changing the background, etc?

Answer (score 0):

Beside the fact you probably need to rethink how your model works. titleForHeaderInSection just wants a string and UIKit will handle the rest. So don't return `String(describing: cell)` cause that will just be the name of the cell. You need to return that string you're trying to set the textLabel to. So keep the switch but for each case, instead of

`cell?.textLabel?.text = "{Letter}"`

do this:

`return "{Letter}"`

and remove the let cell... line and the last return line